# Do we have a non factorial function which is Θ(n!)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

So i know that  `f(n)=n^n` has a bigger growth compared to `g(n)=n!` and `t(n)=2^n` has a less growth

but i can't find any function that has the same order as n! and is not a factorial function

do we have such a function which is Θ(n!) and is not factorial? if we do have such functions then can you mention a few?

Comment: Any function that is n!+o(n!) is Theta(n!). For example: n!+1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - one of the most famous [asymptotic equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) of `n!` is given by its [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), namely:

```
(1)  n! ~ sqrt(2.pi.n).(n/e)^n
```

Note the use of *equivalence* which is *stronger* than the Θ relationship. The former implies the latter:

```
(2)  f(n) ~ g(n) => f(n) = Θ(g(n))
```

With (1) and (2) you get:

```
n! = Θ(sqrt(2.pi.n).(n/e)^n)
```

Since you are asking for a Θ approximation rather than an equivalence, you can create as many functions as you want, for instance multiplying by `2 - sin(n)` (which isn't particularly useful!):

```
n! = Θ((2 - sin(n)).sqrt(2.pi.n).(n/e)^n)
```

Comment: if f(n) = Theta(g(n)) then it doesn't follow that f(n) = Theta(sin(n)g(n)). Because sin(n) is arbitrarily close to 0. "Bounded" is not strong enough -- you need it also to be bounded below by some constant greater than 0 (or equivalently g(n) and 1/g(n) are bounded).

Comment: @PaulHankin Thank you for reporting the mistake

Answer (score 1):

A simple example is computing all possible permutations of an array:

- n choices for first element
- n - 1 for 2nd
- n - 2 for 3rd
- and so on ...

In total there are n(n - 1)(n - 2)... = n! permutations (if elements are unique or tagged).

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Double Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) and try to compare them.